# Decode audio data in real time

Tags: javascript, audio, decode

I have found this: https://kazuki.github.io/opus.js-sample/

If i put this code:

```
else{
    console.log(ev.data);
}
```

on line 617 in file test.js

The console outputs the decoded data (I suppose).

I want to make an html/js file like the above to decode real time streaming audio.

I have no written any code with Promises, so i am new to this code style.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true,video:false})
                    .then(function(stream) {
                        //decode opus stream
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Until the new codec API becomes available, you really can't.  The best you can do is pipe this data into an audio element with MediaSource Extensions.  What specifically are you trying to build?

Comment: I want to have a python user and a browser user and i want to voice connect them.

Comment: You'll want to use WebRTC for that.  Otherwise, latency will build and build, not to mention that the recorder won't reliably give you audio segments ever 200 milliseconds as you're requesting.  I'm not a regular Python user, so I don't know what you'd use for that on the Python side... but this looks promising:  https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc

Comment: @Brad Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65099562/peer-to-peer-client-with-peerjs-and-python-user